# Selenium Webdriver. Getting same text from different pages

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I'm using ChromeDriver to access TripAdvisor.com and searching for "fishing" activities. I can extract all the information about the providers on the first page using:

```
    String myText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search_result\"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]")).getText();
    System.out.println(myText + "\n");
```

The result:

Osprey Cruises
797 reviews
1 Padre Blvd, South Padre Island, Texas
fishing matches 328 reviews
Fishing was very good I caught about a dozen sand trout. They allowMay 20, 2017

But when I go to the next page:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search_result\"]/div/div[3]/div/a[2]")).click();
```

and trying to extract the result from the second page using

```
    String myText2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search_result\"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]")).getText();
    System.out.println(myText2 + "\n");
```

I'm getting the XPath by using Chrome and inspecting the element on page 2.
It is giving me the same result from the page one:

Osprey Cruises
797 reviews
1 Padre Blvd, South Padre Island, Texas
fishing matches 328 reviews
Fishing was very good I caught about a dozen sand trout. They allowMay 20, 2017

How can I get the result from page 2? I'm new to Selenium and any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You do realize that in your second code sample you're still trying to print out `myText` which is the string from the first page? It that a typo and should be `myText2`, or it that your issue?

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo, i changed the code accordingly. Regardless, it is still giving me the same results. @MivaScott

Comment: Can you update the question with relevant _HTML_ ?

Comment: I fixed the issue. Thanks for your time. @DebanjanB

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed the issue. I just had to wait until the first element loaded and then try to get the text.

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    By firstResult = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search_result\"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]");

    // get the "firstResult" element
    element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(firstResult));//waits until "firstItem" is loaded
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));
```

Then get the text:

```
    String myText2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search_result\"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]")).getText();
    System.out.println(myText2 + "\n");
```